# Android ImageView gets out of borders

Tags: android, scroll, border, android-imageview

i'm trying to make a simple app, that loads a bitmap image in an imageview, that can be zoomed and scrolled.I can zoom in and out and scroll around the imageView but it always gets out of borders(black screen). Even though i copied a very helpful code to help me out, imageview still gets out of screen. Can you please help me get this right ?
Posting full code, a bit too long.
Thanks in advance.

```
package something;


public class LoadMap extends Activity {

ZoomControls zoom;
ImageView img;
ImageButton linkButton;

float startX, startY;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_map);

    Resources res=getResources();
    final Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.map); 
    BitmapDrawable bDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, mBitmap); 

    //get the size of the image and  the screen
    int bitmapWidth = bDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int bitmapHeight = bDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int screenWidth = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();  
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int screenHeight = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    img = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    // set maximum scroll amount (based on center of image)
    final int maxX = (int)((bitmapWidth / 2) - (screenWidth/ 2));
    final int maxY = (int)((bitmapHeight / 2) - (screenHeight / 2));

    // set scroll limits
    final int maxLeft = (maxX * -1);
    final int maxRight = maxX;
    final int maxTop = (maxY * -1);
    final int maxBottom = maxY;

    zoom = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls1);
    linkButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.info);

    startX = img.getScaleX();
    startY = img.getScaleY();            

    img.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

    final int pointX = (int) img.getX();
    final int pointY = (int)img.getY();

    img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            float downX, downY;
            int totalX, totalY;
            int scrollByX, scrollByY;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                float currentX, currentY;

                switch (event.getAction())
                {   
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        downX = event.getX();
                        downY = event.getY();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        currentX = event.getX();
                        currentY = event.getY();
                        scrollByX = (int)(downX - currentX);
                        scrollByY = (int)(downY - currentY);

                        // scrolling to left side of image (pic moving to the right)
                       if (currentX > downX) {
                            if (totalX == maxLeft) {
                                scrollByX = 0;
                            }
                            if (totalX > maxLeft) {
                                totalX = totalX + scrollByX;
                            }
                            if (totalX < maxLeft) {
                                scrollByX = maxLeft - (totalX - scrollByX);
                                totalX = maxLeft;
                            }
                        }
                        // scrolling to right side of image (pic moving to the left)
                        if (currentX < downX) {
                            if (totalX == maxRight) {
                                scrollByX = 0;
                            }
                            if (totalX < maxRight) {
                                totalX = totalX + scrollByX;
                            }
                            if (totalX > maxRight) {
                                scrollByX = maxRight - (totalX - scrollByX);
                                totalX = maxRight;
                            }
                        }

                        // scrolling to top of image (pic moving to the bottom)
                        if (currentY > downY) {
                            if (totalY == maxTop) {
                                scrollByY = 0;
                            }
                            if (totalY > maxTop) {
                                totalY = totalY + scrollByY;
                            }
                            if (totalY < maxTop) {
                                scrollByY = maxTop - (totalY - scrollByY);
                                totalY = maxTop;
                            }
                        }

                        // scrolling to bottom of image (pic moving to the top)
                        if (currentY < downY) {
                            if (totalY == maxBottom) {
                                scrollByY = 0;
                            }
                            if (totalY < maxBottom) {
                                totalY = totalY + scrollByY;
                            }
                            if (totalY > maxBottom) {
                                scrollByY = maxBottom - (totalY - scrollByY);
                                totalY = maxBottom;
                            }
                        }

                        img.scrollBy(scrollByX, scrollByY);
                        downX = currentX;
                        downY = currentY;
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        linkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/infopoint.bg");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);                  
            }
        });

        zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                float x = img.getScaleX();
                float y = img.getScaleY();

                img.setScaleX((float) (x+1));
                img.setScaleY((float) (y+1));                   
            }
        });

        zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                float x = img.getScaleX();
                float y = img.getScaleY();

                img.scrollTo(pointX, pointY);

                if((x>startX) & (y>startY)) {
                    img.setScaleX(startX);
                    img.setScaleY(startY);
                }
            }
        });
}
}
```

I'm interested in the onTouch method, where i "try" to calculate the max borders, but i can scroll top and bottom to black screen, and when trying to scroll left and right i can only scroll 3/4 of the image. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ImageViewTouch](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) and [GestureImageView](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview)

You can use these custom views or examine the source code to see how it is working.